# Removing matching variables from a dataframe without merge()

Tags: r, filter

I have two data frames with one column: `originId`

My objective is to remove from `data` all rows where `originId` is equal to `originId` in `filter`

Is there a one-step method of performing this task in R without using `merge()` and then subsetting ?  If so, what would that be?

```
> dim(filter)
[1] 3790    1
> dim(data)
[1] 100110      1

> head(filter)
      originId
454  359720489
1519 359720489
2584 359720489
3649 359720489
4714 359720489
7456  -5378234


> head(data)
  originId
1 -5378234
2 -5357893
3 -5357892
4 -5355561
5 -5355558
6 -5355320
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data[!duplicated(data[data$originId,])]
```

Comment: @the_darkside you may get unique values in originId

Comment: yes however the values are not all unique and I want to keep all values, even if they are duplicated, in `data$originId` if they do not match `filter$originId`

Comment: @the_darkside you can use the  jimbo code if you want the same data[ !data$originId %in% filter$originId, ]

Comment: when I try this I receive an empty dataset

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
a <- c(1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1)
b <- c(1, 5, 6)
a[ !a %in% b ]
[1] 2 3 4
```

`a` corresponds to your `data`, and `b` is the `filter` vector. Thus, the `1` must be filtered in `a`. You can find all numbers in `b` in `a` using `%in%`. Output is a logical vector which is turned around by `!`. output is a subset of `a` without the numbers in `b`.

In your case you should type:

```
data[ !data$originId %in% filter$originId, ]
```

Comment: this for some reason produced an empty dataset...does it matter that `originId` is a factor?

Comment: No it should not be a matter. Using your data above, everything works fine for me. Please post your code for subsetting.